# comparing pointer with integer. How to fix it?

Tags: c

here is piece of my code, I want to check if there are no element next, exit the program. 
but i get warning of comparing pointer with integer. how i can fix it, cheers.

error is this part
if(nums[i] == NULL)

```
/* scanf the file, and store the value in the nums */
for(i = 0; i < numOfInt; i++){

   fscanf(f, "%d", &nums[i]);

   /* check if the value is too big */ 
   if(nums[i] == NULL){  
 printf("arg1 is not equal to nums of element in the file\n");
 exit(1);
   } 
 }
```

Comment: It would help if we knew what "nums" was declared as.

Answer (score 13):

Look at the documentation of `fscanf`, it doesn't work like that. Use rather its return value.

```
ret = fscanf(f, "%d", &nums[i]);

if (ret != 1)
    /* error */
```

Answer (score 3):

Lets assume that `nums` is an array of integers.

You are then comparing an integer with `NULL`. `NULL` is used for pointers.

Is is like comparing apples with oranges.

It is worthwhile to familiarize yourself with the manual pages and take note of the return values.

The function in question returns the number of items interpreted.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming nums is an int[]. NULL is usually a void* (pointer), so it doesn't make sense to compare nums[i] which is and int, to a pointer.